# SQL join two tables using value from one as column name for other

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a bit stumped on a query I need to write for work.  I have the following two tables:

```
|===============Patterns==============|
|type       | bucket_id | description |
|-----------------------|-------------|
|pattern a  | 1         |  Email      |
|pattern b  | 2         |  Phone      |


|==========Results============|
|id     | buc_1     | buc_2   |
|-----------------------------|
|123    | pass      |         |
|124    | pass      |fail     |
```

In the results table, I can see that entity 124 failed a validation check in buc_2.  Looking at the patterns table, I can see bucket 2 belongs to pattern b (bucket_id corresponds to the column name in the results table), so entity 124 failed phone validation.  But how do I write a query that joins these two tables on the value of one of the columns?  Limitations to how this query is going to be called will most likely prevent me from using any cursors.

Comment: What do you need to get in the result? You cannot "join" them in such fashion, but you can make a specific join clause for each `buc_X` column.

Comment: Can you restructure your tables?  This is not a good implementation of a normalized database.  Everytime you add a new pattern, you'll need to add a new column to your results table...

Comment: which version of oracle DB do you have ? You should look into the PIVOT and UNPIVOT concept - http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

Comment: Btw, by work, do you mean college/school work or company work ?

Comment: Sadly, these tables belong to the client, so I can't touch them. I'm just the sorry guy who has to pull the data in them!

A join clause for each bucket would be unpleasant, but may be necessary if I can't figure this out.

Looking at PIVOT... that may work.  I've never used that before, so I'll have to do some experimentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An other approach if you are using Oracle ≥ 11g, would be to use the [`UNPIVOT` operation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/analysis.htm#sthref1185). This will translate columns to rows at query execution:

```
select * from Results
unpivot ("result" for "bucket_id" in ("buc_1" as 1, "buc_2" as 2))
join Patterns
using("bucket_id")
where "result" = 'fail';
```

Unfortunately, you still have to hard-code the various column names.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3eae/17

Comment: Steam mentioned pivot/unpivot above, but I'm glad to see an example of the syntax!  Pretty neat function!  I was able to use this to get to where I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some crude solutions:

```
SELECT "id", "description" FROM
Results JOIN Patterns
ON "buc_1" = 'fail' AND "bucket_id" = 1

union all 

SELECT "id", "description" FROM
Results JOIN Patterns
ON "buc_2" = 'fail' AND "bucket_id" = 2
```

Or, with a very probably better execution plan:

```
SELECT "id", "description" FROM
Results JOIN Patterns
ON "buc_1" = 'fail' AND "bucket_id" = 1
OR "buc_2" = 'fail' AND "bucket_id" = 2;
```

This will report *all* failure descriptions for each `id` having a fail case in bucket 1 or 2.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3eae/8 for a live example

---

That being said, the *right* solution would be probably to change your schema to something more manageable. Say by using an [association table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) to store each failed test -- as you have in fact here a [many to many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29).

Comment: I wish changing the schema were an option!  I was a little annoyed when I saw the tables.  That union idea is pretty clever!  I may be able to use that, though I'll have to see how the execution time is.  Although I'll primarily be pulling one id at a time, there will be millions of values in the results table.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that what you really want to know is the description(in your example Phone) of a Pattern entry given the condition that the bucket failed. Regardless of the specific example you have you want a solution that fulfills that condition, not just your particular example.

I agree with the comment above. Your bucket entries should be tuples(rows) and not arguments, and also you should share the ids on each table so you can actually join them.  For example, Consider adding a bucket column and index their number then just add ONE result column to store the state. Like this:

```
  |===============Patterns==============|
  |type       | bucket_id | description |
  |-----------------------|-------------|
  |pattern a  | 1         |  Email      |
  |pattern b  | 2         |  Phone      |


  |==========Results====================|
  |entity_id     | bucket_id    |status |
  |-------------------------------------|
  |123           | 1            |pass   |
  |124           | 1            |pass   |
  |123           | 2            |       |
  |124           | 2            |fail   |
```

1.-Use an Inner Join: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp and the WHERE clause to filter only those buckets that failed:

2.-Would this example help?

```
 SELECT Patterns.type, Patterns.description, Results.entity_id,Results.status
 INNER JOIN Results
 ON
 Patterns.bucket_id=Results.bucket_id
 WHERE
 Results.status=fail
```

Lastly, I would also add a primary_key column to each table to make sure indexing is faster for each unique combination.

Thanks!